# How do i pass multiple parameters from list in sqlalchemy filter statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, string-parsing

the user returns a string where is parse to apply the filter in sqlalchemy.
but the numbers of parameters are unknown.
eg:

```
def fun_name(user_id, value):
  return db.query(table)
         .filter(or_(table.column_name.like('%'+value+'%')))
```

this would work if the value is a string where i could apply a filter with that value.

But now I have this situation:

```
def fun_name(user_id, values):
  values_lst = values.split(',')
  return db.query(table)
         .filter(or_(table.column_name.like('%'+ values_lst[0] +'%'), 
                     table.column_name.like('%'+ values_lst[1] +'%')))
```

This works only if the split has two parameters,
But how do I handle, if I don't know exactly the size of the list in prior?

Is there a generic way to parse this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my Friend, who saved my day with the answer.
The solution is

```
def fun_name(user_id, values):
  values_lst = values.split(',')
  return db.query(table)
         .filter(or_(*[table.column_name.like(f'%{val}%') for val in values_lst]))
```